# Integrating $\int_{D} \ln(x^2+y^2) \ dx \ dy$ over $D= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \frac14 \leqslant x^2+y^2 \leqslant4, y\geqslant 0 \}$

Tags: integration, solution-verification

> Let $D= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \frac14 \leqslant x^2+y^2 \leqslant4, y\geqslant 0 \}$. Compute $$\int_D \ln(x^2+y^2) \ dx \ dy.$$

Converting to polar coordinates I have that $D= \{(r, \theta) \mid \frac12 \leqslant r \leqslant 2, 0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \pi \}$ and the integral becomes $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{\frac12}^{2} \ln(r^2) \ dr \ d\theta = \int_{0}^{\pi} 5\ln(2)-3 \ d\theta = \pi(5\ln(2)-3).$$

I'm not entirely sure I've done this correctly. Is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Should be $rdrd\theta$

Comment: You forgot the Jacobian of the change: $r$.